# Move an attached to a task document to another node

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Greetings to the community, I am using alfresco 6.0.0 Community Edition and I would like to move a document attached to a task to another node on the complete event of the task.

I found from here  https://community.alfresco.com/thread/204737-workflow-parallel-group-review-with-move  about this "move" function so what I am currently doing is the following:

1. Start the process
2. Attach an item to the task that I have created using the

> /tasks/{taskId}/items (POST) 
>   method of the alfresco REST API.

3. Complete the task

The part of my bpmn where I move the file is below:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                 <activiti:string> 

                   java.lang.System.out.println(bpm_package.children.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++){
                     bpm_package.children.move("b162be92-fb36-44f0-83c1-4432b8261c5a");
                    }
                 </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
           </activiti:taskListener>
```

Where **b162be92-fb36-44f0-83c1-4432b8261c5a** is the node id of a folder I have created.

Unfortunately, when i complete this task I get the following error:

> Node Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content, Node Aspects: [{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}auditable, {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}referenceable, {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}localized]
>   0.0
>   2018-11-15 15:43:24,936  ERROR [impl.interceptor.CommandContext] [http-apr-8080-exec-3] Error while closing command context
>    org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Exception while invoking TaskListener: Exception while invoking TaskListener: 10150807 Failed to execute supplied script: 10150806 TypeError: Cannot find function move in object Node Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content, Node Aspects: [{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}auditable, {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}referenceable, {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}localized]. (AlfrescoJS#10)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.fireEvent(TaskEntity.java:742)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.complete(TaskEntity.java:184)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:52)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:24)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.NeedsActiveTaskCmd.execute(NeedsActiveTaskCmd.java:59)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
>           at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
>           at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
>           at org.activiti.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.complete(TaskServiceImpl.java:178)
>           at org.alfresco.rest.workflow.api.impl.TasksImpl.update(TasksImpl.java:821)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1556.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Could anyone shed light on this please? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem was that the **move** function expects a node element not the id I passed to it (String).

Fixed code below:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
             <activiti:string> 
                for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++){
                 var p = bpm_package;
                 var doc = p.children[i];
                 var myNode = initiatorhome.childByNamePath("foldertomove/testFolder"); <!-- the names of the nodes under the root directory where the file should be moved to-->
                 doc.move(myNode); 
                }
             </activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
       </activiti:taskListener>
```